# Invalid architectures Xcode 10

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode10

I upgraded Xcode 10 and submitted my app. I got a email that I have not changed the architectures Setting. The Valid architectures is armv7 and arm64.

App Store Connect

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "#####!". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

Invalid architectures - This app has invalid architecture, and may have been built with invalid build settings or incompatible tools. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version. If you are using third party development tools, contact the provider.

Best regards,

The App Store Team

Comment: This could be an issue to CocoaPods, have you tried to update your pods as well?

Comment: What libraries and frameworks are you using?

Comment: You can try using legacy build system instead of new build system.
There is some change in architecture as can be seen in the link: https://developerbetas.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Xcode_10_Beta_Release_Notes.pdf

Comment: I do not have CocoaPods.I can build on my iphone and Simulators. So i  think libraries and frameworks may not have problems.

Comment: Hello NoProb,I have tryed  legacy build system. Also have this email.I can upload success,but

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you @LabsPanda

Comment: I received the same email. I'm at a loss to explain.

Comment: By any chance, is your deployment target less than 8.0?

Comment: Yes! I have changed my deployment target to 8.0(before it it 6.0). Fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: My deployment target is 8.0 but still getting the same error. Can any one face this issue

Comment: I solved this by changing deployment section in the build settings tab, it has been mapped to version 6 for debug and release any version, I made it to 10 and submitted it got through the test flight for compliance section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode 10 doesn't support deployment targets lower than 8.0. You will either need to update the deployment target, or alternatively, if you need a lower target you can reinstall Xcode 9.4.1.

Comment: Even if the deployment target is 8.0 we will require Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section  Deprecation Notices Deprecations in this link

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes!
>   
>  With xcode 10:
>   recommend to set a deployment target of macOS 10.9 or later, or iOS 7 or later.

**Just modify Deployment Target to 7.0 will fix this issue.
(Tested And Passed)**

And ... there has more info.
 before got "Invalid architectures" from Apple.
when i update xcode to 10. i got a compile error with

> libstdc++.6 not found.
>   
> (My Deployment target is 6.0)

For fixed this. i have download the old(xcode 9) libstdc++ files from a github rep.
The Apple release note can also explain this error.

> So if you build for ios 6.0, recommend to use xcode 9.
>   otherwise
>   Use xcode 10 and Deployment target 7.0 or later.